# Enable Admin Console on WildFly 12 running in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, wildfly-12

I installed WildFly server today into Eclipse, and I'm able to run web applications. I'd like to be able to log in to the Admin Console. I haven't enabled it though, so I see this :

```
Your WildFly Application Server is running.
However you have not yet added any users to be able to access the admin console.

To add a new user execute the add-user.bat script within the bin folder of your WildFly installation and enter the requested information.
```

Well, I ran the add-user.bat script in the bin directory of my wildfly install. It seemed to run without any problems. I still get the same error.

I'm guessing that Eclipse copies my wildfly install and places it in some hidden directory. No idea where that is though. Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you first remove wildfly from eclipse then add-user then add wildfly to eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Section 3.3 of the **Wildfly 12 Admin Guide**](http://docs.wildfly.org/12/Admin_Guide.html#Default_HTTP_Interface_Security) describes the process for adding a user in order to be able to access Wildfly's admin console:

> To manipulate the files and add users we provide a utility add-user.sh
>   and add-user.bat to add the users and generate the hashes, to add a
>   user you should execute the script and follow the guided process.
>   The full details of the add-user utility are described later but
>   for the purpose of accessing the management interface you need to
>   enter the following values: -
>
> - Type of user - This will be a 'Management User' to selection option a.
> - Realm - This MUST match the realm name used in the configuration so
>     unless you have changed the configuration to use a different realm
>     name leave this set as 'ManagementRealm'.
> - Username - The username of the user you are adding.
> - Password - The users password.
>
> Provided the validation passes you will then be asked to confirm you
>   want to add the user and the properties files will be updated.
>
> For the final question, as this is a user that is going to be
>   accessing the admin console just answer 'n' - this option will be
>   described later for adding slave host controllers that authenticate
>   against a master domain controller but that is a later topic.
>
> Updates to the properties file are picked up in real time so either
>   click 'Try Again' on the error page that was displayed in the browser
>   or navigate to the console again and you should then be prompted to
>   enter the username and password to connect to the server.

There are a couple of potential pitfalls when running the *add-user* utility:

- You must select option *a) (Management User)* for the *type of user*.
- You must use realm *ManagementRealm*, though this should happen automatically if the type of user being added is *Management User*.

But rather than diagnosing what went wrong, it's easier just to try adding another user, following the directions given in the documentation shown above. For reference, here's a screen shot of what I did, where the yellow horizontal bars are points at which I submitted something from the keyboard:

[image: addUserUtility]

After running **add-user.bat** I was able to login to the **Admin Console** (http://localhost:9990) using the user I had just created, and no server restart was necessary. My environment was Eclipse Photon on Windows 10.

If you are still having problems, open the file **mgmt-users.properties** to see whether your user was added successfully. In my case a line was added for the new user that looked like this:

```
skomisa=82fa5e2f2de46d60adf210bb95d461f3
```

Comment: You did turn out to be right. My issue was that I somehow had two installations of wildfly and I was running add-user.bat on the wrong one. For anyone with this problem in the future, you can view the install location by creating a new server, create new runtime, select wildfly and then the path to your runtime should be shown.